# Opencart get select value to controller for filter

Tags: select, opencart

I have page called **no.tpl**, in this page am displaying customer name in `select dropdown`

this is the code:
**no.tpl**

```
<select name="customer_id" id="customer" style="width: 325px;margin-bottom:10px" class="form-control">
    <?php foreach($customerData as $customer){ ?>
        <option value=<?php echo $customer['customer_id']?>><?php echo $customer['customer_name']?></option>
    <?php }?>
</select>
```

In controller page i have to filter selected customer list

```
$queryCustomer = $this->db->query("select customer_id, concat(firstname, ' ',lastname) as name, email from " . DB_PREFIX . "customer where customer_id='6'");
             $selectedCustomer = $queryCustomer->row;
             $selectedCustomerId = $selectedCustomer['customer_id'];
             $selectedCustomerName = $selectedCustomer['name'];
             $selectedCustomerEmail = $selectedCustomer['email'];
```

I want `customer_id='6'` as selected `customer_id`. I mean pass the select value to controller page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in view page

```
<select name="customer_id" id="input-sales-person" style="width: 325px;margin-bottom:10px" class="form-control">
    <?php foreach($customerData as $customer){ ?>
        <option id="temp" value=<?php echo $customer['customer_id']?>><?php echo $customer['customer_name']?></option>
    <?php }?>
</select>

 <input type="submit" id="noOrder" Onclick="return ConfirmDelete();" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
```

Use this following script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#noOrder').on('click', function() {
        var temp1=$( "#input-sales-person option:selected" ).val();
        var temp2=$( "#input-sales-person option:selected" ).text();
        document.cookie = "selectedCustomerId=" +temp1;
        document.cookie = "selectedCustomerName=" +temp2;
        location="index.php?route=sale/no";
    });
</script>
```

In controller pass the `customer_id` as `$selectedCustomerId=$_COOKIE['selectedCustomerId'];`

```
$selectedCustomerId=$_COOKIE['selectedCustomerId']; /*customer_id=6*/

$queryCustomer = $this->db->query("select customer_id, concat(firstname, ' ',lastname) as name, email from " . DB_PREFIX . "customer where customer_id='".$selectedCustomerId."'");
```